# Filtering Results Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a database and want to filter some dates. The problems is that I have to filtering the same columns two times and one of them I want de Nan rows. What should I do ?

```
df = (df[df['column'] > 1992])
```

What should I add to my code to also filtering the Nan results

Comment: can you show a example of your dataframe an your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter a column and drop null values, you can just do -

```py
df[df['column'] > 1992].dropna()
```

If you want to filter the df by multiple conditions and drop nulls, do -

```py
df[(df['column'] > 1992) & (df['column'] < 2018)].dropna()
```